# XML Schema order of elements

Tags: xsd

In my XSD, I want to be able to specify that the order of the elements doesn't matter. This is what I have:

```
<xs:element name="ADT_A08_231_GLO_DEF">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EVN_EventTypeSegment" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PID_PatientIdentificationSegment" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PD1_PatientAdditionalDemographicSegment" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

How can I make it so that the EVN and PID element can occur random (first EVN then PID or first PID element and then the EVN element) in the XML file?

```
<EVN_EventTypeSegment>Test</EVN_EventTypeSegment>
<PID_PatientIdentificationSegment>PIDTest</PID_PatientIdentificationSegment>
```

or:

```
<PID_PatientIdentificationSegment>PIDTest</PID_PatientIdentificationSegment>
<EVN_EventTypeSegment>Test</EVN_EventTypeSegment>
```

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this? Because you probably don't want to do this.

Comment: What do you mean? I have to be able to do this, I receive certain messages from a customer and I have to process this. Now the order of some fields of the messages can be different, so in my schema I have to take this in acount.. Is there really no way I can achieve this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I made this possible by using a choice group :D

Comment: an example would've been a bit more helpful

Comment: The drawback of a choice group here is that it does not solve the problem described:  the choice group must repeat, in order that both EVN and PID can occur, and then there is no constraint that neither EVN nor PID can repeat.

Answer (score 36):

Use `xs:all` instead of `xs:sequence`.

Comment: There is little point in adding new answers that add no new information to old posts, however, your answer is easier to read, so +1'd

Answer (score 22):

Change the `xs:sequence` in your schema document to `xs:all`.  An all-group containing references to (or declarations of) elements A, B, and C is satisfied if and only if A, B, and C are present in some order.  The elements may have `minOccurs` set to 0 to make them optional (like your `PD1_PatientAdditionalDemographicSegment` element).

In XSD 1.0, the children of an all-group must have `maxOccurs` of 1, which some people find uncomfortably restrictive, but in your case that's what you want anyway.  In XSD 1.1 that restriction is lifted.