# Validating out of order xml in python

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I have an XML Schema file that for the purpose of the example I'll use [W3 school's](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_howto.asp) one as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="note">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    </xs:schema>
```

And I want to use it to validate an XML file that has the same elements, and definitions as the XSD like the following:

```
    <note
    xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/schema.xsd">
      <to>Tove</to>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
```

The problem is, as, in the example, the server sends the elements out of order, so, when I run the code bellow, it tells me that the XML is invalid, even though I only have valid elements.

```
    import xmlschema
    
    xsd_file = "schema.xsd"
    xml_file = "input.xml"
    
    xmlschema.validate(xml_file, xsd_file)
```

Is there a way that I can validate this input in python ignoring the order that the elements appear on?

This is the current error message when executing that code:

> XMLSchemaChildrenValidationError: failed validating <Element '{https://www.w3schools.com}note' at 0x000002B13C7E7090> with XsdGroup(model='sequence', occurs=[1, 1]):

> Reason: Unexpected child with tag '{https://www.w3schools.com}heading' at position 2. Tag 'from' expected.

Schema:

```
     <xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string" />
         <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string" />
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
```

Instance:

```
      <note xmlns="https://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com/schema.xsd">
        <to>Tove</to>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <from>Jani</from>
        <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
      </note>
```

```
Path: /note
```

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971799/xml-schema-order-of-elements

Comment: The thing is, I can't alter the XSD file, nor the XML, I'll receive this from the server, I can only alter the validation

Comment: Tell the people maintaining the server to change the XSD or don't use it.  You'll have to parse the XML and walk the tree to validate it according to your requirements.

Comment: Their code in C# that they use to generate the XML is able to read it fine, isn't there any way I could simply ignore the order?

Comment: If you don't use a validating parser you can do whatever you want.  You only have a problem if you use a validating parser and the XML doesn't conform to the rules established by the schema.

Comment: The XML is not valid (Using the XSD you have provided). The options you have 1) change XSD 2) change XML 3) Do not validate against XSD